# C++ [Linker Error] Undefined Reference to

Tags: c++

I am working on a C++ project where I have my main.cpp and two class files as View and Model. So my main looks like,

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "view.h"
#include "model.h"


using namespace std;

int main()
{
    View v;
    v.showLogin();


}
```

view.h looks like

```
#ifndef VIEW_H
#define VIEW_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
/*
 * No description
 */
class Model;
class View
{
     string username,password; 

    void validateLogin(string u, string p); 
    public:
        // class constructor
        View();
        // class destructor
        ~View();
    public: 
     void showLogin(){

         cout<< "_________________ User Login _________________"<<endl;
         cout<<'\n'<<endl;
         cout<< "Enter Username : ";
         cin>>username;
         cout<< "Enter Password : ";
         cin>>password;
         validateLogin(username,password);
         //system("pause > NULL");



         }  
    public:
           void showHome(){
                cout<< "_________________ ! Welcome to AppLine ! _________________"<<endl;
                cout<<'\n'<<endl;
                cout<< "1. Add a Job"<<endl;
                cout<< "2. Search a Job"<<endl;
                cout<< "2. Modify a Job"<<endl;
                system("pause > NULL");

                }     

};

#endif // VIEW_H
```

view.cpp looks like

```
#include "view.h" 
#include "model.h"
// class's header file

// class constructor
View::View()
{

    // insert your code here
}

// class destructor
View::~View()
{
    // insert your code here
}
```

model.h looks like

```
#ifndef MODEL_H
#define MODEL_H
#include <iostream>
#include <string> 

using namespace std;
/*
 * No description
 */
class View; 
class Model
{
    void showHome();  
    public:
        // class constructor
        Model();
        // class destructor
        ~Model();

    public:
           void validateLogin(string u, string p){

                if(u=="admin" && p=="1234"){
                     showHome();
                     }


                }   
};

#endif // MODEL_H
```

and model.cpp looks like

```
#include "model.h" // class's header file
#include "view.h"
// class constructor
Model::Model()
{
    // insert your code here
}

// class destructor
Model::~Model()
{
    // insert your code here
}
```

So while I'm trying to compile and run the program I get the annoying error below

**[Linker Error] Undefined Reference to 'View::validateLogin(std::string,std::string)'
Id returned 1 exit status**

Please help me

Comment: Both `View` and `Model` have declarations for a function called `validateLogin`, while only `Model` has a definition. Which class do you want to have this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declared `validateLogin` in `View` class, but defined it in `Model` class. Simplest fix is to remove the

```
void validateLogin(string u, string p);
```

line from the `View`'s header.

Or move the definition from `Model` to `View`.

Comment: So then how I'm going to use validateLogin using forward declaration inside Model class ?

Comment: @DilukshanMahendra To use `validateLogin` you always need an instance of an object which has this method defined. So if you want it in `Model` then you need to have a pointer to `Model` in `View` to call for example: `model->validateLogin(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `validateLogin` in View and not in Model.

```
class Model // see you are defining validateLogin in Model
{
    void showHome();  
    public:
        // class constructor
        Model();
        // class destructor
        ~Model();

    public:
           void validateLogin(string u, string p){

                if(u=="admin" && p=="1234"){
                     showHome();
                     }
```

Comment: It would be a logical mistake to validate logins in a view.

Comment: So then how I'm going to use validateLogin using forward declaration inside Model class ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight True. But, I am trying to solve his technical problem. But login code should be in Controller, right?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you promised the compiler that there would be `validateLogin` function in the `View` class, but you failed to define. Instead, you defined one in the `Model` class, which is the correct place for such function to be. Now you need to add a reference to `Model` to your `View` class, so that you could call `model.validateLogin()` in your implementation file:

```
class View {
    string username,password;
    Model &model;
    // validateLogin is removed
public:
    // class constructor
    View(Model& m) : model(m) {};
    ...
};
```

You will need to move the code of `showLogin` into cpp file, because you cannot call `validateLogin` until `Model`'s interface is fully declared.

Now change your `main` to make a `Model` before the view, and give that model to the `View`'s constructor:

```
int main()
{
    Model m;
    View v(m);
    v.showLogin();
}
```